# How to inject EJB Session to ADF ManagedBean

Tags: ejb, oracle-adf, inject

I'm researching about Oracle ADF and EJB. I'm using ADF faces as View and Controller, EJB as service. I don't want to use ADF model to bind EJB Session to interact with ADF faces. So, I have create a managed bean to interact with ADF faces

**ManagedBean**

```
public class EmployeeManagementController {
    private List<Jobs> jobList;
    private RichTable jobTable;
    private RichPanelGroupLayout panelGroup;

    //@EJB(mappedName = "HRSysDemo.JobBean",name = "jobBean")
    @EJB
    private JobBeanLocal jobBean; 
    /*...*/

    public void initPage() {
        System.out.println("TESTING . . .");
        jobList = jobBean.getJobsFindAll();
    }
}
```

**Session Bean**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "HRSysDemo/JobBean")
public class JobBean implements JobBeanRemote, JobBeanLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Model")
    private EntityManager em;
    /*...*/
    public List<Jobs> getJobsFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Jobs.findAll").getResultList();
    }
}
```

My problem is "jobBean" always get "null", it means EJB Session can not inject to ManagedBean. I have tried some ways, such as change interface injection (Remote interface), specify name and mappedName, but it's still not working. So, ***how can I inject a EJB SessionBean into a ADF ManagedBean?***

Thank in advance!

Comment: Does the two models in an EAR and the EJB module registered right in the WAR module?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use Eclipse, I'm using Jdeveloper :/

Comment: It is not an IDE specific file format. It is a packaged J2EE app format (ready to deploy).

Comment: I know. 'cause EAR is concept of Eclispe IDE, Jdeveloper is not exist. Everything is deployed in a WebLogic,
See my project deploy on Weblogic
http://sv1.upsieutoc.com/2017/03/28/asasa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it by following some step in [here](http://codeplay.net/2010/09/14/inject-ejb-to-adf-managed-bean/), It's not working well but I have fixed them. I hope this will be helpful for someone else:

Here my code:

**ELResolverWithInjectEJB.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.MapELResolver;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import oracle.adf.controller.metadata.model.beans.ManagedBean;
import oracle.adf.controller.metadata.model.beans.ManagedBeanScopeType;

/* Illegal internal package import. Please use public API */
import oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.AnnotationUtils;
import oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory;
import oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ScopeMap;

public class ELResolverWithInjectEJB extends MapELResolver {
    private static Method getManagedBeanScopeType = null;
    private static Method shouldIncludeHigherScopes = null;
    private static Method newInstance = null;
    static {
        try {
            getManagedBeanScopeType = ScopeMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("getManagedBeanScopeType", null);
            getManagedBeanScopeType.setAccessible(true);
            shouldIncludeHigherScopes = ScopeMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("shouldIncludeHigherScopes", null);
            shouldIncludeHigherScopes.setAccessible(true);
            newInstance = ManagedBeanFactory.class.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", ManagedBean.class);
            newInstance.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ELResolverWithInjectEJB() {
        super();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.semantic-warning")
    public Object getValue(ELContext elContext, Object base, Object var) {
        ScopeMap scope = (ScopeMap) (base instanceof ScopeMap ? base : null);
        if (scope == null || scope.containsKey(var))
            return super.getValue(elContext, base, var);
        Object bean = null;
        try {
            ManagedBeanFactory mbf = ManagedBeanFactory.getInstance();
            ManagedBean managedBean = mbf.getManagedBeanInCurrentPageFlow((String) var);
            ManagedBeanScopeType expectedScope = (ManagedBeanScopeType) getManagedBeanScopeType.invoke(scope, null);
            if (((Boolean) shouldIncludeHigherScopes.invoke(scope, null)) &&
                (managedBean == null || !managedBean.getScope().equals(expectedScope))) {
                managedBean = mbf.getManagedBeanInAdfPageFlow((String) var);
                }
            if (managedBean != null && managedBean.getScope().equals(expectedScope)) {
                bean = newInstance.invoke(mbf, managedBean);
                if (bean != null) {
                    scope.put((String) var, bean);
                    EJBInjector.inject(bean);
                    AnnotationUtils.runPostConstructIfSpecified(bean, managedBean.getName(), managedBean.getScope());
                    elContext.setPropertyResolved(true);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }

    static class EJBInjector {
        private static Map<String, List> processed = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
        private static Map<String, String> mappedBean = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
        private static Context ctx = null;
        static {
            try {
                ctx = getInitialContext();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static void inject(Object o) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NamingException {
            List<AccessibleObject> inj = null;
            if (!processed.containsKey(o.getClass().getName())) {
                inj = Lists.newArrayList();
                for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.getAnnotation(Autoinjector.class) != null) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        inj.add(field);
                        Autoinjector rm = field.getAnnotation(Autoinjector.class);
                        mappedBean.put(convertKey(o, field), rm.ejbMappedName());
                    }
                }
                processed.put(o.getClass().getName(), inj.isEmpty() ? null : inj);
            }
            inj = inj != null ? inj : processed.get(o.getClass().getName());
            if (inj != null) {
                for (AccessibleObject i : inj) {
                    ((Field) i).set(o,ctx.lookup(mappedBean.get(convertKey(o, (Field) i)) + "#" +
                                                   ((Field) i).getType().getName()));
                }
            }
        }

        private static String convertKey(Object o, Field f) {
            return o != null && f != null ? o.getClass().getName() + "_" + f.getType().getName() + "_" + f.getName() :
                       "";
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,[your_provide]);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, [your_url_server]);
            return new InitialContext(env);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Autoinjector.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Autoinjector {
    String ejbMappedName() default "";
}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
    <default-render-kit-id>oracle.adf.rich</default-render-kit-id>
    <el-resolver>[your_package].ELResolverWithInjectEJB</el-resolver>
</application>
```

**In controller**

```
public class DicOrgDetailPageController extends BaseController {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2332665929048532518L;

    /* -- Services -- */
    @Autoinjector(ejbMappedName = "mytest")
    private SB_DicOrgService sbDicOrgService; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining your beans in the adfc-config? IF so it might not work - try defining them in a regular faces-config file instead.

Comment: I don't define them in the adfc-config file:(. I defined them in faces-config.